# Matlab GUI for array of spots

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I need to create a GUI in Matlab. It requires me to identify the spots for two images, and calculate the distance between them.

I have obtained the code for finding and encircling a single spot. It is as follows:

```
function [meanx,meany] = centroid(pic)
[x,y,z] = size(pic);
if(z==1)
    ;
else
    pic = rgb2gray(pic);
end

% N=2;
% image = interp2(double(pic),N,'spline');
image = sort(sort(pic,1),2);
image =reshape(image,1,numel(image));
i=0;
while(i<3)
         if(image(end)==image(end-1))
                image(end)=[];
         else
             image(end)=[];
             i=i+1;
         end
end
    threshold = image(end);
        pic2 =(pic>=threshold);
pic=(pic-threshold).*uint8(pic2);
% % image=(pic-threshold+1).*uint8(image);     %minus threshold


[rows,cols] = size(pic);
x = ones(rows,1)*[1:cols];
y = [1:rows]'*ones(1,cols);

area = sum(sum(pic));
if area ~= 0
    meanx = sum(sum(double(pic).*x))/area;
    meany = sum(sum(double(pic).*y))/area;
else
    meanx = cols/2;
    meany = rows/2;
end
```

However, I need it to work for multiple spots as shown below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbvdD.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmxG6.jpg

So far, I have come up with this, but it only circles separate spots and not all together. 
PLEASE HELP - I need to encircle at least 10X10 spots and store their values, and do this for two images as shown above, and find the distance between them!

```
img1 = imread('r0.bmp');
centroidmat=zeros(10,10,2);
for numx=1:2
    for numy=1:2
        single_spot=img1((numx*220+780):((numx+1)*220+780),(numy*220+1272):((numy+1)*220+1272),:);
        figure
        imshow(single_spot);
        figure

        [cx,cy] = centroid(single_spot);
        centroidmat(numx,numy,1)=cx;
        centroidmat(numx,numy,2)=cy;
        imshow(single_spot);
        hold on;
        plot(cx,cy,'og')

    end
end
```

Please HELP GUYS! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ? -

```
centroidmat=zeros(10,10,2);
for numx=1:2
    for numy=1:2
        single_spot=img1((numx*220+780):((numx+1)*220+780),(numy*220+1272):((numy+1)*220+1272),:);

        [cx,cy] = centroid(single_spot);
        centroidmat(numx,numy,1)=cx;
        centroidmat(numx,numy,2)=cy;

        figure,
        imshow(single_spot);
        hold on;
        plot(cx,cy,'og') 
    end
end
```

I have only removed the redundant **figure** and **imshow(single_spot);** at the start of the loop, as they appear again later on inside the same loop.